# asp.net/ews meeting request get attendees

Tags: c#, asp.net, exchangewebservices

i´m trying to send meeting requests through an asp.net application and then check if the attendees accepted or not.

First Method i´m using: "To send the meeting requests"

```
    protected void meetingTest_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        string[] split = User.Identity.Name.Split('\\');

        string userTag = split[1];

        Active_Directory ad = new Active_Directory();

        string creator = ad.convertForUserInfo(userTag, "email");


        ExchangeService service = new ExchangeService();
        service.AutodiscoverUrl(creator);

        Appointment meeting = new Appointment(service);

        meeting.Subject = "test";
        meeting.Body = "test2";
        meeting.Start = DateTime.Now.AddDays(2);
        meeting.End = meeting.Start.AddHours(4);
        meeting.Location = "test3";
        meeting.RequiredAttendees.Add("Attendee´s emailadress");
        meeting.ReminderMinutesBeforeStart = 60;
        meeting.Save(SendInvitationsMode.SendToAllAndSaveCopy);


        checkMeetings();
    }
```

And the sending part works fine, i get a meeting request in my outlook and i can see the required attendees in there.

Now here my Method to get those required attendees and their status:

```
    private void checkMeetings()
    {

        string[] split = User.Identity.Name.Split('\\');

        string userTag = split[1];

        Active_Directory ad = new Active_Directory();

        string creator = ad.convertForUserInfo(userTag, "email");

        ExchangeService service = new ExchangeService();
        service.AutodiscoverUrl(creator);

        CalendarFolder folder = CalendarFolder.Bind(service, WellKnownFolderName.Calendar);

        CalendarView view = new CalendarView(Convert.ToDateTime("03.08.2015 08:00"),Convert.ToDateTime("08.08.2015 08:00"));

        FindItemsResults<Appointment> results = folder.FindAppointments(view);

        foreach (Appointment appointment in results)
        {

            var attendees = appointment.RequiredAttendees;

            Test1.Text += appointment.RequiredAttendees.Count() + "***";

            foreach (var attend in appointment.RequiredAttendees)
            {

                Test2.Text += attend.Name + " " + attend.ResponseType + "***";

            }

            //Test2.Text += appointment.Subject + "***";

        }
    }
```

My problem now is, that "appointment.RequiredAttendees.count()" is 0, even though i added an attendee when i sent the meeting request...

Does anybody know why? Or is there maybe a simpler solution to this, that i haven´t found so far?

Comment: sry, i forgot to say i´m new to that kinda stuff (asp.net), what do you mean with "session"?

Comment: session holds data in your ASP to prevent data lost when the page is post back

Comment: try this sir in your meetingTest_Click

add on the button this code `Session["Appointment"] = meeting;`

and in your checkmeeting method call and set a value for your session like this `meeting = (Appointment)Session["Appointment"];`

but im also new in ASP.net i hope you get it....

Comment: i tried another solution and it worked, gonna post it here! But thanks for your answer

Answer (score 2):

OK i found a solution to my own problem, gonna post it in case someone runs into the same problem.

```
    private void checkMeetings()
    {

        string[] split = User.Identity.Name.Split('\\');

        string userTag = split[1];

        Active_Directory ad = new Active_Directory();

        string creator = ad.convertForUserInfo(userTag, "email");

        ExchangeService service = new ExchangeService();
        service.AutodiscoverUrl(creator);

        CalendarFolder folder = CalendarFolder.Bind(service, WellKnownFolderName.Calendar);

        CalendarView view = new CalendarView(Convert.ToDateTime("03.08.2015 08:00"),Convert.ToDateTime("08.08.2015 08:00"));

        FindItemsResults<Appointment> results = folder.FindAppointments(view);

        foreach (Appointment appointment in results)
        {

            Appointment appointmentDetailed = Appointment.Bind(service, appointment.Id, new PropertySet(BasePropertySet.FirstClassProperties) { RequestedBodyType = BodyType.Text });

            foreach (Attendee attendee in appointmentDetailed.RequiredAttendees)
            {
                Test2.Text += attendee.Name + " " + attendee.ResponseType + "***";
            }

        }
    }
```

The part which fixed it was:

Appointment appointmentDetailed = Appointment.Bind(service, appointment.Id, new PropertySet(BasePropertySet.FirstClassProperties) { RequestedBodyType = BodyType.Text });

now i can get every atendee and see if they accepted it or not

Answer (score 2):

The better way to load additional properties is like this:

```
private void checkMeetings()
{

    string[] split = User.Identity.Name.Split('\\');

    string userTag = split[1];

    Active_Directory ad = new Active_Directory();

    string creator = ad.convertForUserInfo(userTag, "email");

    ExchangeService service = new ExchangeService();
    service.AutodiscoverUrl(creator);

    CalendarFolder folder = CalendarFolder.Bind(service, WellKnownFolderName.Calendar);

    CalendarView view = new CalendarView(Convert.ToDateTime("03.08.2015 08:00"),Convert.ToDateTime("08.08.2015 08:00"));

    FindItemsResults<Appointment> results = folder.FindAppointments(view);
    service.LoadPropertiesForItems(appointments, new PropertySet(BasePropertySet.IdOnly, AppointmentSchema.Subject, AppointmentSchema.Start, AppointmentSchema.RequiredAttendees));

    foreach (Appointment appointment in results)
    {

        foreach (Attendee attendee in appointment.RequiredAttendees)
        {
            Test2.Text += attendee.Name + " " + attendee.ResponseType + "***";
        }

    }
}
```

The important line is this one:

```
service.LoadPropertiesForItems(appointments, new PropertySet(BasePropertySet.IdOnly, AppointmentSchema.Subject, AppointmentSchema.Start, AppointmentSchema.RequiredAttendees));
```